# How to make different element for each row in numpy array variable?

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

I try to make the output y that have different element per row. But when I print y again, the output show that y have the same element for each row. What is the correct way to create y with different element for each row?

```
import numpy as np
class temp:
  x = []
y = np.tile(temp, (3, 1))
y
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxdYU.png)

```
for i in range(3):
  y[i, 0].x = np.random.rand(1,5)
  print(y[i,0].x)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTRbA.png)

```
for i in range(3):
  print(y[i,0].x)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISchR.png)

Comment: `np.tile(temp, (3, 1))` just makes three references to the `temp` class (not an instand of the class, the class itself).  `object` dtype arrays are virtually the same as lists.  If you want multiple instances you need to write something like `[temp(), temp(), temp()]`.

Comment: I try to make `y = [temp(), temp(), temp()]` but I can't access x from y

Comment: You have to use `y[0].x`

Comment: the output is `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x'` if i use `y[0].x`

Comment: since you passed `(3,1)` to `np.tile()`, you should try `y[0,0].x`, `y[1,0].x`... in your original code, or, try `y[0].x` where `y = [temp(), temp(), temp()]` as suggested by hpaulj

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to make arrays of custom class objects.  This will not replicate the MATLAB `struc` (in your next question).

But if you do define a class, use a more conventional format, such as:

```
In [39]: class Temp:
    ...:     def __init__(self, x):
    ...:         self.x = x
    ...:     def __repr__(self):
    ...:         return f'Temp ({self.x})'
    ...:         

In [40]: a = Temp([1,2,3]); b = Temp([4,5])

In [41]: a
Out[41]: Temp ([1, 2, 3])

In [42]: a.x
Out[42]: [1, 2, 3]

In [43]: b
Out[43]: Temp ([4, 5])
```

`a` and `b` are instances of the class, each with their own `x` attribute.